# Using system.windows.forms with XNA

Tags: winforms, forms, xna

I am making a game that uses XNA. I would like to add things to the game such as buttons, textboxes, labels, tooltip texts, and other stuff that comes with system.windows.forms. How do I merge system.windows.forms with XNA? Are there any API's or DLL's that I could implement to get this to work?

Thanks,

BenShums

Answer (score 7):

The bad news: in short, no, it is not possible (at least, in a straightforward way). While it is true that you can use a System.Windows.Forms control as a canvas for your game, you cannot use an XNA device as a canvas for your control.

The good news: there are already some alternative toolkits that create textboxes, buttons and labels using XNA.

http://forums.xna.com/forums/p/1891/9461.aspx