# How to use XNA in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xna

So... I want to make a game, and I want to write it in C#. In the past, I've made a mario clone using C++ and OpenGL. I quite like OpenGL, but I don't know how well it's supported inside C#/WPF. Also, it might be beneficial to use an actual game library? I guess XNA is *the* game library for C#, so maybe I'll invest a bit of time learning that.

However, I want to use WPF form controls for my level editor... is there any way that I can embed an XNA (DirectX?) window inside a WPF app?

Specifically, I don't need any buttons or things *inside* the XNA/DirectX widget, just *around* it, so no mixing required...just need to get a graphics widget in my WPF form.

Comment: Have you managed to get the mouse to work with XNA/WinForms? I'm trying to do the same. Keyboard works, but mouse input isn't updating in my XNA-panel.

Comment: @SpicyWeenie: No, sorry. I never got anywhere with this project. I'm writing an SDL wrapper for C# now... it has excellent keyboard/mouse/controller support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Nick Gravelyn explains how to do it on his blog.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/nicgrave/rendering-with-xna-framework-4-0-inside-of-a-wpf-application)

Although, if it's just for an editor, you may find using [WinForms](https://web.archive.org/web/20150116165519/http://create.msdn.com:80/en-US/education/catalog/sample/winforms_series_1) is easier and better supported.

Comment: Haha...two checkmarks for you sir! Found my cross-post in no time.

Answer (score 2):

WPF uses DirectX, and you can do direct "interop" [here is a codeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/D3DImage.aspx) on the subject.  [Here is an article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/iersoy/256/Default.aspx) i dug up where the author is using win-forms and WPF controls in an XNA project.  Might be worth a look for you.

Comment: K... I thought so, but... that doesn't really answer the question. I think XNA offers sprites and things that you can render in a DirectX context?? If I'm able to embed a DirectX widget, and then use all the XNA tools on it..then great.. how do I embed DirectX?

Comment: @mark I dug up a link on google that might be what you are looking for, added it to the "answer".

Comment: re: codeproject: uses interop which I don't think is necessary.. XNA nor WPF uses interop AFAIK, so why should I need to when I put them together? re: wpf controls in xna game: I want to go the other way around... XNA in WPF.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should ask this on gamedev.stackexchange.com. But I've seen a tutorial embedding XNA.

You should check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258048/using-system-windows-forms-with-xna) question and [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/xnagamestudioexpress/thread/eebea7f5-6640-4791-bb65-bb30ca9f1dd1/) page. They are on Windows Forms, but they'll help.

Also check [this](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/6471.aspx) and [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/xnaframework/thread/370b8555-c028-4e3d-b678-12cd36ca55c6/) articles.

Keep in mind one thing. XNA is meant to be used for the whole game, integration would be useful on making level editors like you say, but not for a full game.

Comment: I think your first two links talk about putting controls *inside* the game itself, which is not what I need to do..just around it.